# How to pass data of multiple text boxes from one form to another with button clicking?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm not able to pass data of **multiple text boxes** from `Form1` to `Form2` through a button click. I have tried the following way, but it is not working.

Did I do it wrong? And if so, how can I do it?

Form1 Code:

```
public partial class Form1: Form {
    Form2 frm2;

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnInvoice_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.Hide();

        if(frm2==null)
            frm2=new Form2();

        frm2.ValueFromForm1(txtFirstName.Text);
        frm2.ValueFromForm1(txtLastName.Text);
        frm2.ValueFromForm1(txtCellNo.Text);
        frm2.ValueFromForm1(txtDate.Text);
        frm2.ValueFromForm1(txtDueDate.Text);

        frm2.Show();
    }
}
```

Form2 Code:

```
public partial class Form2: Form {
    public Form2() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void ValueFromForm1(string value) {
        txtFirstName.Text=value;
        txtLastName.Text=value;
        txtCellNo.Text=value;
        txtMaskDueDate.Text=value;
        txtMaskDate.Text=value;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are setting all the textboxes with the same value. seems a bit strange. anyway, what is happening, because this should still show your form2 with all textboxes set to `txtDueDate`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are assigning same value to all textboxes. And result will be last value you are assigning (which is `txtDueDate` text). Create different methods to assign values for each of textboxes, or pass values as array, or as a custom object:

```
public class Invoice
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public string CellNo { get; set; }
   // etc
}
```

On Form1

```
private void btnInvoice_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    if (frm2 == null)
        frm2 = new Form2();

    Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
    invoice.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
    invoice.LastName = txtLastName.Text;
    invoice.CellNo = txtCellNo.Text;
    // etc
    frm2.Invoice = invoice;
    frm2.Show();
}
```

On Form2

```
public Invoice Invoice
{
   set
   {
        txtFirstName.Text = value.FirstName;
        txtLastName.Text = value.LastName;
        txtCellNo.Text = value.CellNo;
        // etc
   }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. As I am new to programming, I don't understand why you have created a class called Invoice. I just have two Forms i.e. Form1 and Form2

Comment: @KiritiK this data transfer class holds all required data which you are passing from Form1 to Form2. Thus your Form2 requires all those data, then it makes sense to hold all data in one place.

Comment: So I have to create a new class called Invoice and add reference to my project ? Is that what it is ?

Comment: @Yes, simply right-click on your Project name and select *Add > Class..* to create new class. Then add all properties to that class, and use it to transfer data between forms.

Answer (score 1):

How about in creating a `Properties` in `Form2`? Creating a `class` is one of the solution but you could simple create `Properties` to `get` and `set`

## Form1

```
private void btnInvoice_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    using(var f = new Form2())
    {
      f.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
      f.LastName = txtLastName.Text;
      f.CellNo = txtCellNo.Text;
      f.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

## Form2

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public string CellNo { get; set; }

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtFirstName.Text = FirstName;
    txtLastName.Text = LastName;
    txtCellNo.Text = CellNo;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The method implementation is very wrong, or atleast the logic you are thinking! You are assigning same value to all textboxes.

You can solve the problem two ways.

#### The easy way is to change the modifier for controls in Form2 from `private` to `internal` or `public`. After changing modifier u can call it like

```
private void btnInvoice_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        if (frm2 == null)
            frm2 = new Form2();

        frm2.txtFirstName.Text = txtFirstName.Text;
        frm2.txtLastName.Text = txtLastName.Text;
        frm2.txtCellNo.Text = txtCellNo.Text;
        frm2.txtDate.Text = txtDate.Text;
        frm2.txtDueDate.Text = txtDueDate.Text;

        frm2.Show();
    }
```

### How to change modifier ?

[image: changing modifier]

---

#### or the complicated way by creating multiple Methods like

```
public void ValueForFirstName(string value)
{
    txtFirstName.Text = value;
}


public void ValuForLastName(string value)
{
    txtLastName.Text = value;
}
```

Comment: that's not really an answer to the question

Comment: @bas - let me complete it first!

Comment: Exactly how can I do it then ?

Comment: @AppDeveloper Thanks. Method one might work, but is there any efficient way to do it ?

Comment: @KiritiK It's not particularly efficient in terms of lines of code; it's a lot of copy-paste and typing.  It's not going to be slow at all in terms of actual runtime speed.  It will be *very* fast.

Comment: @AppDeveloper You do *not* want to publicly expose the inner controls of a Form.  It makes it *much* harder to maintain the interactions between forms, reason about the state of the form, etc.  You should *always* create methods, properties, or some other mechanism to ensure you don't expose the controls.

Comment: @Servy - have stated both the way, i know exposing controls are bad opt, but is a working solution in case of a non-complicated project!

Comment: @AppDeveloper It's developing a bad habit which both inhibits the ability to learn more appropriate practices and is also very likely to cause significant problems as soon as you have non-trivial projects.  The entire purpose of doing simple projects when learning to program is so that you can practice learning proper programming techniques when there are fewer barriers to that learning.  When you discard that concept you end up doing more harm than good.

Comment: I feel that [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782244/how-to-pass-data-of-multiple-text-boxes-from-one-form-to-another-with-button-cli/14782534#comment20699334_14782534) to another answer here applies to your answer as well.